# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError by recursion

Tags: tail-recursion

I write code but it works properly for small inputs and take long time to average size inputs but for big inputs it shows Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
here is my code please help me to solve this issue

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class demo{
    public static long print(long N){
    if(N==0)
        return 0;
    else if(N==1)
        return 1;
    else if(N==-1)
        return -1;
    else 
        return(2*print(N-1)+3*print(N-2));
 }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        long N;
        long cases=0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        N = scan.nextLong();
        if(N<0)
        N*=(-1);
        cases=print(N);
        System.out.println(cases); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From JavaCodeGeeks:

> When a function call is invoked by a Java application, a stack frame is allocated on the call stack. The stack frame contains the parameters of the invoked method, its local parameters, and the return address of the method. The return address denotes the execution point from which, the program execution shall continue after the invoked method returns. If there is no space for a new stack frame then, the StackOverflowError is thrown by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

So, each time your method gets called recursively, it creates a new stack. If the computer on which your program is running cannot allocate memory to such a large number of stacks, the JVM throws a StackOverFlowError.

Depending on the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) installed, the default thread stack size may equal to either 512KB or 1MB. You can increase the thread stack size using the -Xss flag. This flag can be specified either via the project’s configuration or via the command line. The format of the -Xss argument is:
-Xss[g|G|m|M|k|K].

Comment: Yes, if you are OK with using loop instead of recursion you can use that. AFAIK, loops don't create a new stack. Do you want me to write the code?

Comment: I am sorry @Tilak, but, to convert your recursive function to an iterative function (loop), you still need to use Stacks, because it is not possible with only while loop. You will again face the same problem. So, try the above mentioned solution, it should help.